# Как в telebot определить где находится бот?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Пишу телеграмм бота на Python, либа telebot.

Как определить ботом где он находится, в группе или в ЛС?

То есть если в ЛС, боту писать /start он пишет текст: Привет Артем и тд...Но и когда добавляю в группу, он пишет то же самое. Как сделать при добавлении в группу, чтобы бот писал другой текст? Допустим всем привет и тд.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chat.type` покажет, где находится данное сообщение. В `private`, `group`, `supergroup` или `channel`.